# Using ACS with MVC5 (VS 2013) for Social Media as IdPs

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

Have a problem: I am not able to find out a way to use MVC5 (VS 2013) application to use social media (Facebook, Google etc.) as IdPs using ACS. I want to use ACS.

I am not able to find anything on the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my earlier answer. There's a way in VS 2013 to do that. When you create MVC 5 Application, choose `Organizational Accounts` and then choose `On-Premises` option. Enter the URL of the Federation Metadata URL (`https://{youracsnamespace}.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`) in `On-Premises Authority` and your application URL in `App ID URI` and you should be good to go.

[image]